# passing fix array to a function (to modify it)

Tags: arrays, function

i have some fix arrays defined that i need to write with a common function:

```
uint8 myArray_A[3][5];
uint8 myArray_B[3][5];

void doThings(uint8 * in)
{
  *in[0][0] = someValue_0
  *in[0][1] = someValue_1
}
```

This function i will call in another function and give the needed Array to it:

```
void main(void)
{
  doThings(myArray_A);
}
```

Is this the way to do it? Will it work?

Comment: fixed double dimension arrays must always include the size of the first dimension. What you have will not compile.

Comment: sorry, it is second dimension needed

Comment: What is the language? Looks like C/C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this instead.

```
uint8 myArray_A[3][5];
uint8 myArray_B[3][5];

void doThings(uint8 in[][5])
{
  in[0][0] = someValue_0
  in[0][1] = someValue_1
}
```

If the size of the dimensions varies, then you would need to pass that in somehow, and do your own matrix arithmetic, which is frankly machine-dependent so not a good idea:

```
void doThings(uint8 * in, int dim1, int dim2)
{
  in[0*dim2+0] = someValue_0
  in[0*dim2+1] = someValue_1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a pointer to an integer, that is the location of a single integer in your memory space.
It means that as you pass the pointer to your array (that is the address of the 1st element in your array - `&myArray_A[0][0]`) you lose the structural information that was contained in the definition of `myArray_A` - the size of the array.

This can, however, be fixed by specifying the array parameters in the function declaration.
This can be either done by defining your array type with `typedef int[3][5] my_array_t` or by specifying the array size in the parameter `void doThings(uint8[3][] in)`

- Bonus: `#define` your array sizes so that you can update the size in only a single location and have the change propagate across your code.